# Is it possible to remake database from existing website?

Tags: php, database

1)
Recently I received  website's source code. In this website everyone can create an account, add advertisements, pictures etc. I have to remake the database from this source code. Is it possible? I do not know neither the name of the database, nor table names etc.

2)
When I am trying to enter the website (which I've hosted on my own xampp server) I receive an alert and some code in browser(see below). Is it because there is no database for the website?

Alert box - "*ALERT3*"

Code in browser -

```
$sessionID, 'locale_id' => $locale, 'user_id' => $data['user_id'], 'data' => $data);
    } else { print_content('
```

Here is the code which is responsible for this alert

```
if ($_GET['act'] == 'login' && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
if (check_user($_POST['email'], password($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']))) {
    $data = get_user_data($_POST['email']);
    $sessionID = create_session_id($data);
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = array('session_id' => $sessionID, 'locale_id' => $locale, 'user_id' => $data['user_id'], 'data' => $data);
} else {
    print_content('<script>alert("_ALERT3_");location.href="/main/"</script>');
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible yes, but you'd save yourself a huge headache from checking for all the possible tables and fields by just asking for a copy of the database schema from the original developer.

Comment: It is. But honestly, if you have to ask i don't think you should be the one doing it.

Comment: You'd need to know what the check_user function does to know if this alert is because there is no database connection. I mean, sure, it's a safe bet, the user isn't valid, but you should really read through the code to determine things like this.

Comment: You will be banging your head on the desk every day because there is always going to be one more field you missed.

Comment: Possible? Yes. But this won't be a job you'll enjoy.

Comment: That's the thing - the website was developed approximately 7 years ago and there is only source code left and no database schema.
And when i read through the code i couldn't find any table names which is my main concern.

Comment: Threre's nothing we can do for you. The answer to your question is "Yes, it's possible". But you will have to dig through the source, find the queries, understand what is needed and re-create the tables accordingly. And if you already did so and didn't find the table names (or what makes up the table names when run)  ...you have a long, long road ahead of you.

Comment: Find and read every query and build the tables and column from those.